# Stoke's Theorem Example - Help?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

From Stoke's Theorem:
\begin{equation*} \oint_c \textbf{F}\centerdot d\textbf{r}= \int\int_S (\nabla \times\textbf{F})\centerdot d \textbf{S}\end{equation*}
Evaluate $\oint _C \textbf{F}\centerdot d\textbf{r}$ by Stoke's Theorem if $\textbf{F}=<1,-2x,3>$ and C: $x^2+y^2=1$.

Choose S to be the hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, where  $z \geq 0$.

==================================================================

The above example is the only one given to us on Stoke's Theorem by our lecturer. I am only able to solve it without using Stoke's Theorem, as I am unsure how to go about solving the double integral of the sphere in order to use Stoke's Theorem.

Can anybody please give me some advice as to how to go about solving this integral using Stoke's? It is VERY important that I get this example, as it is the only one that I will have to reference when practising other examples for my multivariable examination coming up in two week's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Stokes' Theorem

$$\oint_{C}\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \int_{S} (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \mathbf{n}dS$$

where the surface $S$ is defined by $z = h(x,y) = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ with $-1\leq x \leq 1$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}.$

We have $\mathbf{F}=(1,-2x,3)$ and

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = (0,0,-2),$$

and the outward unit normal vector at $S$ is

$$\mathbf{n}=\frac{(-h_x,-h_y,1)}{\sqrt{1+h_x^2 + h_y^2}}.$$

The differential element of surface area is

$$dS={\sqrt{1+h_x^2 + h_y^2}}dxdy.$$

Hence,

$$\int_{S} (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \mathbf{n}dS = 2\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}(-2)dxdy= -2\pi$$

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it - this certainly helped A LOT! Only thing I noticed, is that you wrote "dxdy" instead of "dydx" - other than that this solution worked perfectly! :).

Comment: It definitely helped! :). Thank you very much! :). Thanks to this example, I'm now able to solve the other examples of Stoke's in my textbook as well. :).